# How to compare two arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to compare two arrays:

```
compareFrom = []
compareTo = ["John Doe", "Eric Schulz", "Tom Jerry"]
```

I tried the following:

```
arrayField1 = []
for r in empData
  compareFrom << r.employeeName
end

if compareFrom.include?(compareTo)
  #yes got it
end
```

I cannot figure out why I get `false` even though `compareFrom` has the same values as `compareTo`.

Is there anything that I need to change in the code?

Comment: Ruby style dictates names like `compare_from` in preference to `compareFrom` as capital letters have significant syntactical meaning. The `for` statement is also almost never used as `emp_data.each |r|` is the more typical form.

Comment: What is `empData` and where does `employeeName` come from? Is that part of the example code actually needed to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`Array#include?` only tests membership of one element in an array. Your `compare_from.include?(compare_to)` tests whether `compare_to` is an element of `compare_from`, and would e.g. return `true` in case `compare_from` is `[1, 2, 3, ["John Doe", "Eric Schulz", "Tom Jerry"], 5]`.

If you want to see if all elements of `compare_to` are in `compare_from`, `compare_to.all? { |element| compare_from.include?(element) }` is idiomatic and legible but slow; tadman's `(compare_from & compare_to).size == compare_to.size` is much more performant. A third option, when speaking of subsets, and the one I'd likely prefer, is to use sets:

```
require 'set'
Set[compare_to].subset?(Set[compare_from])
```

Comment: Hmm, why not math notation, `Set[compare_to] <= Set[compare_from]` or `Set[compare_from] >= Set[compare_to]`?

Answer (score 1):

This code boils down to:

```
compare_from = emp_data.map(&:employee_name)
```

Where that's calling the `employee_name` method on each of the items in the `emp_data` array and returning a new array with the result. You can easily test overlap on two arrays using `&` to find the intersection:

```
compare_to = ["John Doe", "Eric Schulz", "Tom Jerry"]
common = compare_from & compare_to
```

If that array `common` has any entries then you have matches.